# Python static variables

Tags: python, static-variables

I am trying to have a single static variable as an 'id' for all the child instantiations of this parent class.  The problem I'm having is double counting of this ID, likely because the parent's `__init__` gets called twice.  But if I remove the explicit `Parent().__init__()` call, then the counter doesn't get incremented at all.  How do I get the id to increment only ones?  Here's my code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
class Parent:
    cls_id = 0

    def __init__ (cls):
        cls.cls_inc_id()

    @classmethod
    def cls_inc_id (cls):
        cls.cls_id += 1

    @classmethod
    def child_inc_id (self):
        self.id += 1


class Child1 (Parent):

    def __init__ (self):
        Parent().__init__()
        self.id = super().cls_id
        print ("Child1 id: ", self.id)

class Child2 (Parent):

    def __init__ (self):
        Parent().__init__()
        self.id = super().cls_id
        print ("Child2 id: ", self.id)


child1 = Child1()
child2 = Child1()

child3 = Child2()
child4 = Child2()
```

My output is:
**%> ./static_vars.py**

```
Child1 id:  2
Child1 id:  4
Child2 id:  6
Child2 id:  8
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sorry, what is it exactly you are trying to accomplish? What is the output *you expect*?

Comment: As an aside, don't use `cls` as the name of the first argument to `__init__`. Conventionally, it should be `__init__ (self)` since it is an *instance method*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you're not using `super` constructor correctly, but also I would reference the actual class in the parent class, not the instance `self` which you incorrectly named `cls`:

```
class Parent:
    cls_id = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = Parent.cls_id
        Parent.cls_id += 1


class Child1(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print ("Child1 id: ", self.id)


class Child2(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print ("Child2 id: ", self.id)


child1 = Child1()
child2 = Child1()

child3 = Child2()
child4 = Child2()
```

```
Child1 id:  0
Child1 id:  1
Child2 id:  2
Child2 id:  3
```

If you wanted a separate ID per type of class, you could use a dictionary mapping class to id:

```
from collections import defaultdict


class Parent:
    cls_ids = defaultdict(int)

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = Parent.cls_ids[type(self)]
        Parent.cls_ids[type(self)] += 1
```

```
Child1 id:  0
Child1 id:  1
Child2 id:  0
Child2 id:  1
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using the collections package. I'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 2):

It gets incremented twice because of `Parent().__init()`.  That creates a brand-new object, initializes it, then discards it.  You should use `super().__init__()`, and in your `__init__ method refer to` Parent.cls_inc_id`.  Then it will work.

And by the way, in `Parent.__init__` you call the parameter "cls", but it's actually "self" -- that's an object method, not a class method.

New code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
class Parent:
    cls_id = 0

    def __init__ (self):
        print("Parent.__init__")
        Parent.cls_inc_id()

    @classmethod
    def cls_inc_id (cls):
        print("Parent.cls_inc_id")
        cls.cls_id += 1

    @classmethod
    def child_inc_id (cls):
        print("child_inc_id")
        cls.id += 1


class Child1 (Parent):

    def __init__ (self):
        print("Child1.__init__")
        super().__init__()
        self.id = super().cls_id
        print ("Child1 id: ", self.id)

class Child2 (Parent):

    def __init__ (self):
        print("Child2.__init__")
        super().__init__()
        self.id = super().cls_id
        print ("Child2 id: ", self.id)


child1 = Child1()
child2 = Child1()

child3 = Child2()
child4 = Child2()
```

Output:

```
Child1.__init__
Parent.__init__
Parent.cls_inc_id
1
Child1 id:  1
Child1.__init__
Parent.__init__
Parent.cls_inc_id
1
Child1 id:  2
Child2.__init__
Parent.__init__
Parent.cls_inc_id
1
Child2 id:  3
Child2.__init__
Parent.__init__
Parent.cls_inc_id
1
Child2 id:  4
```

Comment: Also `cls.cls_inc_id()` needs to be `Parent.cls_inc_id()`. Otherwise it creates an instance attribute instead of updating the class attribute.

Comment: Hah! Very good eye!

Comment: @Barmar no it doesn't, because `cls_inc_id` is a `classmethod`

Comment: Yes it does, because he's CALLING it as an object method.  Try it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It will always get provided the class object as the first parameter. It doesn't matter how you call it, it won't create an instance attribute. However, it will create seperate class variables depending on how you call it. i.e. if you use `self.cls_inc_id()`, the `Parent.cls_inc_id` method gets passed either `Child1` or `Child2` depending on the type of `self`

Comment: And honestly, in this case, it doesn't make sense to use it as a class method, might as well just increment `Parent.id` directly

Comment: OK, I misdiagnosed this.  The issue is that having `__init__` call `self.cls_inc_id()` means it called `Child1.cls_inc_id`, but when he fetches `super().cls_id`, that's getting `Parent.cls_id`, which remains stubbornly at 0.

Comment: Right, I'm not actually sure of the behavior the OP is trying to get, i.e., should there just be an ever increasing ID for *any* instance of `Base` (i.e. including instance of subclasses) or for each subclass, a new counter starting at 0

Comment: I am trying to do both (a) get the Base id incremented for every instantiation of the child and (b) have a separate id counter for each child type.  Thanks for the good inputs, much appreciated on the clarity provided.  Gets me going